# Regarding float type precision

Tags: java, floating-point

I can't understand why this

```
float f = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println((int)f);
```

produces the same lines,

As well as why this does

```
Float f2 = (float) Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(f2.intValue());
```

I mean, mantissa length for floating point number is `2^23-1`. How does it manage to keep max_value of integer, which is `2^31 - 1`?

Comment: BTW Don't use `float` is you can avoid it.  `double` gives you half a trillion times the accuracy. Some suggest you should use BigDecimal (not my preference however)

Comment: Well, this sample is just for the sake of sample. Not a real life code.

Comment: True, You can make the same comparison with Long.MAX_VALUE and double.

Answer (score 8):

> How does it manage to keep max_value of integer, which is 2^31 - 1?

It actually doesn't. The value of `f` is `2147483648`.

However, the [narrowing primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) from `float` to `int` clamps the value. It gets to this part:

> - Otherwise, one of the following two cases must be true:
>
>   - The value must be too small (a negative value of large magnitude or negative infinity), and the result of the first step is the smallest representable value of type int or long.
>   - The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the largest representable value of type int or long.

You can see this easily by making the number even bigger:

```
float f = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
f = f * 1000;
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // 2147483647
System.out.println((int)f); // 2147483647
```

Or by casting to `long` instead, which obviously doesn't need to be clamped at the same point:

```
float f = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // 2147483647
System.out.println((long)f); // 2147483648
```

Comment: @dionadar: I like your idea of casting to `long` instead. Will add that to my answer, if that's okay with you.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I'm not sure I've understood it. :/ At first, `f is 2147483648` on mine system it shows smth like `2.14748365E9` and the next explaination, I really don't get it.

Comment: @dhblah: If you print it out *as a float* it will show as `2.14748365E9` - but it really *is* exactly `2147483648`. Does the casting to `long` not make this clearer?

Comment: Am I right to understand that because 2^23-1 can't be represented in float mantissa, it's got rounded to the bigger representable number, which is 2^32 (as float exponent has base 2)? If that's true, then other parts seems to be clear to me.

Comment: Your float represents 1.0 (mantissa is rounded up towards an exact 1) * 2^32 (the exponent is 32, and the implied base is 2). The output 2.14748365E9 is another (rounding) conversion - this time to base 10, your float really is 1*2^32.

Comment: Also I don't understand how "2.14748365E9 can be exactly 2147483648"

Comment: If you round 2.147483648E9 to one 9 significant digits (one before the dot, 8 after) you get 2.14748365E9. This is done to prevent irritating output, since your last digit often becomes useless anyway due to rounding in your computations.

Comment: You mean, that println rounds the output, but actual value of float is 2147483648, right?

Comment: Well, thank you but println source is hidden under sun.misc so I can't verify that your statement is correct.